# How does aggregation work on the integration bus?

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

I built an flow in which I make two parallel http requests using aggregation:

[image]

Depending on the input request, there may be one, two, or no requests at all. The AggregateReply node somehow understands that I made one request, not two. And if two parallel requests occur, then the AggregateReply node waits for both to end, if one request occurs, then it waits for one to end. Please help me and explain how the Aggregate Reply node recognizes these cases. (I read the documentation, but did not understand how it works)

Comment: Can I suggest adding some Trace nodes that write to a file specifying {$LocalEnvironment} for the output after the AggregateControl node and two AggregateRequest nodes you should see some of the content used to manage the the content that the AggregateReply node is looking for.

Comment: Also have a think about how you would write the code for the three different node types so that the Reply node knows how many responses it is waiting for.